# Error starting AVAudioEngine: after playback audio engine configuration changed in background (com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio error 561145187.)

Tags: avfoundation, avaudiosession, avaudioengine, ios-background-mode

I am trying to transmit audio when app is in background and AVAudioSession changed to Headset from speaker or vice versa

Changed output AVAudioSession Port: Speaker/BluetoothHFP

I have tried restarting audioEngine but getting following errors:

[aurioc] AURemoteIO.cpp:1663  AUIOClient_StartIO failed (561145187)

[avae] AVAEInternal.h:109 [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1545:Start: (err = PerformCommand(*ioNode, kAUStartIO, NULL, 0)): error 561145187
Engine Check: Restarted AVAE

Error starting engine: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio error 561145187.)